# Slow training of RL algorith and low cpu usage

Tags: machine-learning, keras, python-3.6

I have a python 3.6.4 script, which is a simple reinforcement learning script based on a 4 layer MLP(input, hidden-128, hidden-256, output). I can't publish my code here cause it is too big, I will post only a small part of it.

```
def train(model, epochs):
    total = 0
    start = time.time()
    entire_hist = []
    profits = []
    for i in range(epochs):
        loss = 0
        accuracy = 0
        hist = []
        env.reset()
        game_over = False
        input_t = env.observe()

        while not game_over:
            input_tm1 = input_t

            if np.random.random() <= epsilon:
                action = np.random.randint(0, num_actions, size=None)
            else:
                q = model.predict(input_tm1)
                action = np.argmax(q[0])

            input_t, reward, game_over = env.act(action)

            exp_replay.remember([input_tm1, action, reward, input_t], game_over)    
            inputs, targets = exp_replay.get_batch(model, batch_size=batch_size)

            loss, accuracy = model.train_on_batch(inputs, targets)
            hist.append([loss, accuracy, env.main])

            print(f'counter: {env.counter}, action taken: {action}, reward: {round(reward, 2)}, main: {round(env.main)}, secondary: {env.secondary}')

            if game_over:
                print('GAME OVER!')

        entire_hist.append(hist)
        profits.append(total)
        print(f'total profit: {env.total_profit}')
        print(f'epoch: {i}, loss: {loss}, accuracy: {accuracy}')
        print('\n')
        print('*'*20)


    end = int(time.time() - start)
    print(f'training time: {end} seconds')
    return entire_hist, total
```

The problem is, that when I run it, CPU usage is only about 20-30% and GPU usage is about 5%. I tried running on different machines and I get similar results, the more powerful CPU I use, less % of it script uses.
And it would be ok, unless it would take a few days to train such a small network if running it for 1000-5000 epochs. Can someone help to make it train faster and increase the cpu usage.
I tried running on both cpu/gpu version of tensorflow.
My set up:
Latest keras with tensorflow backend
Tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was quite simple, I was just using not all of my cores. Since my system was disributing load from one core to all 4 I didn't notice that.